# Preg_replace_callback и шаблонизатор

Tags: шаблонизаторы, preg_replace

Здравствуйте. Пишу сайт с нуля, и для самых-самых основ нужен самый простой шаблонизатор, а именно:

1. {lng:project} - перевод project из
       массива языка, массив такого типа:
   array( 'project' => 'Проект' )
2. {tpl:something/sometpl} - импорт
       .tpl шаблона по директории
       templates/ТЕМА/something/sometpl.tpl

Сложности у меня с функцией preg_replace_callback, да и впринципе с тем, что нужно, чтобы это работало нормально.

Я знаю, что готового мне никто не даст, но я очень прошу помочь с таким относительно легким заданием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал тебе пример на коленке, посмотри - вопросы в комменты. Все должно быть понятно.
Есть невнятный момент - ключевая конструкция, например lng:, вызывается как функция. С архитектурой не помогу, так как задача очень поверхностная.

```
<?php
$input = "{lng:project} {tpl:2}";
global $arr;
$arr  = [
  'project' => 'Test'
];

function lng($param){
  global $arr;
  return sprintf("<?='%s'?>",$arr[$param]);
}

function tpl($param){
  return parse(file_get_contents(sprintf("%s.tpl", $param)));
}

function parse($input){
    $regex = "/\{(lng|tpl)\:((?:[0-9a-zA-Z\/]+))\}/";

    if (is_array($input)) {
        list($exp, $cmd, $arg) = $input;
        return $cmd($arg);
    }

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'parse', $input);
};

$output = parse($input);

echo $output;
?>
```

2.tpl:

```
123
```

Вывод:

```
<?='Test'?> 123
```

Comment: Просто идеально! Спасибо вам =) Накидал бы репутации, но у меня ее нет =( 

И еще раз спасибо, удачки вам. Как смогу - накидаю репы)

Comment: @Alex_Wells, замётано ;) Не забудь отметить ответ как принятый